# Deployed app using Zipdeploy UI on Azure throws an error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

i can deploy an app using Azure service extension in visual studio code which also creates web.config file and the app works fine, but when i try to upload the ZIP file using ZIPdeployUI and manually add the web.config the app throws an error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page". The difference is using Visual studio code the files are uploaded straight into /wwwroot folder and with ZipdeployUI it creates another folder that was zipped on local system.

Comment: could you please clear the question - 1) Are you deploying azure functions or azure web app through VS code Zip Deploy or Visual studio zip deploy? 2) Whatever the application you're deploying either azure functions or azure web apps, what is the stack (like .Net, python, node js etc) you're using in that application? 3) could you please mention the steps you're following for zip deployment?

Comment: Any update to the issue?

Comment: i used Zipfolder npm module

zipFolder('C:/Project/build', 'C:/Project/build.zip', function(err) {
if(err) {
console.log('oh no!', err);
} else {
console.log('EXCELLENT');
}
});

Answer (score 0):

`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

That is basically a hint that Azure encounter an error while running your web app. Since it's in production, it does not show any useful error messages. For testing/debugging purposes you can turn on the Azure detailed messaging, and turn it back off when it's ready for production. To do so, you have to follow these two steps,

- Log in to Azure > App Services (left side menu) >  `Your Web App`  > App Service logs (search box is at the top if you can't find it), then turn on  `Detailed Error Messages`  or turn on all of the logging options, up to you.
- Now add the following in your  `Web Config`  file,
- In your  `Web Config`  file add  `<customErrors mode="Off" />`  BEFORE `system.web` closing tag,  `</system.web>`. Similarly, add  `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>`  BEFORE  `</system.webServer>`. Finally, upload the  `Web Config`  to Azure and cross your fingers.

If you follow the steps correctly, that will show the error messages in detail which takes you to figure out the issue.

**Few Error Cases-Resolutions were:**

1. `You do not... this directory...` this error comes when you have restricted IP on IIS Config. Check your web.config file and add your IP address in security section like:

```
<security>
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
<clear />
<add ipAddress="192.168.250.70" allowed="true" />
</ipSecurity >
</security>
```

Remove it if you do not want to restrict any IP address.

2. Check the zip is unpacked in the path `Site>wwwroot>`, else try restarting your function or web app.
3. You might need to tweak this depending on how your application structure looks like after the build like `site\wwwroot\dist\`, but if you have the app name in the folder structure, you might need to: `site\wwwroot\dist\<app-name>\`
4. Sometimes azure active directory authentication was created by Function App / Authentication automatically like (MS Graph - `User.Read`, Azure Service Management -`user_impersonation`). If yes, removing those will work to access the directory.